# Making harvey ball with border style css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a css styling for a harvey ball with an image inside, but so far I haven't figure out a way to do it right. This is what I have now:

```css
.three {width: 43px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 4px;
  border-left-color: #dadad9;
  border-top-color: #009ee3;
  border-right-color: #009ee3;
  border-bottom-color: #009ee3;
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
}

.lead-name {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family:Symantec Sans;
  color:#424242;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom:0px;
}

.lead-title {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family:Symantec Sans;
  color:#424242;
  margin-top: -3px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="lead-designer">
  <img class="three"  src="http://orig09.deviantart.net/09e7/f/2008/159/0/1/side_profile_vector_by_sruphil.png"/>
  <div style="display:inline-block; margin-bottom:0px; margin-top:5px;">
    <p class="lead-name">Designer Name</p>
    <p class="lead-title">Messaging PO</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yiluka/dtauydrz/

What I want is something like

[image]

As you can see, I want the circle to be divided straight and have part of the image grey scaled.

I have a lot of them and I really want to do it in code instead of photoshop to save some labor.

Comment: you can record an action in photoshop to make it not much labor. honestly, i think it would be less labor than converting all the HTML markup to something that  can do this. it could also slow down a page if you had to use JS to convert all of them on the fly, so for perf, photoshop would be better. if you didn't need it as fancy, then CSS alone could handle it, but you need (afaik) a 2nd image or a custom url hard-coded in a ::after rule to turn part B+W.

Comment: @dandavis actually, doing this in css would be quite simple, I'll try and make an example

Comment: @Jacob Gray it's actually much harder than it looks `:)`

Comment: @NenadVracar the problem I am having is aligning the images without using `background-position:fixed`

Comment: I am stuck at rotating that `:after` element https://jsfiddle.net/dtauydrz/2/

Comment: Are all the images the same size?

Comment: This is what I have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/qgmfLx1m/1/. The problems with it are the images **must** be square, and If you want the circle to be larger you have to adjust the numbers a lot

Comment: @JacobGray: "quite simple"? if you can do it in css without changing the html or hard-coding a rule for each user, then i would be VERY impressed. seeing all the attempts below, i stand by my original assessment.

Comment: @dandavis I admit, It is more complicated then I originally thought :P

Comment: @JacobGray: wow, i've never heard anyone on here admit anything; they usually just try to cover up the fact they said anything at all... impressive.

Comment: Haha! Victory at last :D I'll post what i came up with.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it using the pseudo element `::after` - https://jsfiddle.net/dtauydrz/3/

The HTML:

```
<div class="image-container">
  <img class="three"  src="http://orig09.deviantart.net/09e7/f/2008/159/0/1/side_profile_vector_by_sruphil.png"/>
</div>
<div style="display:inline-block; margin-bottom:0px; margin-top:5px;">
          <p class="lead-name">Designer Name</p>
          <p class="lead-title">Messaging PO</p>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.three {
    border-radius: 100%;
    border-left-color: #dadad9;
    border-top-color: #009ee3;
    border-right-color: #009ee3;
    border-bottom-color: #009ee3;
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 4px;
    border-color: #dadad9;
}

.image-container::after{
    content: "";
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -52px;
    background-color: #009ee3;
    -moz-border-radius: 25px 0 0 0;
    border-radius: 25px 0 0 0;
    width: 25px;
      height: 25px; 
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After an hour of messing with it, I finally finished my solution.

## TL;DR

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kgpcq59q/)

[JSFiddle Demo with a kitten(pick this one)](https://jsfiddle.net/rn4tuvxt/)

[JSFiddle Demo with the unhappy king of all kittens(Actually this one is amazing)](https://jsfiddle.net/24wj8dum/)

This solution, after being implemented, renders this(minus, of course, the amazing hand-drawn circle):
[image: hand-drawn-red-circles-and-text]

This solution doesn't require square images, playing with the background-image placement, and is quite easy to implement.

### Let's get started!

First of all, we take your nice `<img>` HTML element, and replace it with this monstrosity of HTML(It really isn't that bad):

```
<div class="image-wrapper">
  <img class="main" src="http://orig09.deviantart.net/09e7/f/2008/159/0/1/side_profile_vector_by_sruphil.png">
  <div class="grayscale">
    <img class="gray" src="http://orig09.deviantart.net/09e7/f/2008/159/0/1/side_profile_vector_by_sruphil.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Now for a little explanation. We use two different image elements so we can gray-scale one of them. We **do not** use a background image, since this requires a massive amount of changes if you want to make the icon bigger, or the images are different sizes.

`.image-wrapper` is the container div, the elements inside are positioned relative to it. It's CSS is stupid simple:

```
.image-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
```

(If you can't understand that CSS, go read HTML5 and CSS3 for dummies. That's how I started with css... #destroying_my_reputation)

`.main` is, of course, the main image in color. It's CSS is a little mor complicated, but still very basic:

```
.main {
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 5px solid #dadad9;
}
```

The width can be changed to whatever you want, if you do change the width, make sure you also change the width of the `.gray` image. `border-radius:100%` makes a circle, and `border` obviously adds a border.

Now on to the more complicated CSS(It's all pretty simple)!

`.grayscale` is the div used to hold the gray-scale image. If you know CSS, you can probably tell what is happening.

```
.grayscale {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 100% 0 0 0;
  background: #009ee3;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

The div is positioned absolute at the top-left corner of `.image-wrapper`. Anything overflowing it is hidden. It's top-left corner is given a `border-radius` of 100%, making it into the quarter-circle shape. Instead of a border, we change it's background color, and add a padding. This is because if we use a border, it is added to all sides, messing up the desired shape.

And then the `.gray` img:

```
.gray {
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50% 0 0 0;
}
```

Simple, the image is changed to gray-scale using the `grayscale()` CSS filter. Make sure the width is the same as `.main`. And a border radius to add the round effect.

### That's a wrap!

[And here is the long awaited demo, with all the code](https://jsfiddle.net/kgpcq59q/)

Comment: +1 looks good - no alternative to the filters I suggested - but still a complete solution. However you could flip the image horizontally to perfect it.

Comment: @sjkm I didn't have a problem with the filters, just that imho, the OP probably wouldn't have been able to figure out what they wanted from your answer :D

Answer (score 1):

I just created a div that has the shape of a quarter circle

```
.quarter-circle-top-left {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 50%;
   height: 50%;
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
   border-radius: 100px 0 0 0;
   -moz-border-radius: 100px 0 0 0;
   -webkit-border-radius: 100px 0 0 0;
   border-left: 4px solid #009ee3;
   border-top: 4px solid #009ee3;
}
```

And absolutely positioned that div on top of your image. It's got a transparent gray background and a top and left border with your blue. Both are now contained within an wrapper div so that the quarter circle would have something to be relative to.

Here's where the quarter circle css came from: http://1stwebmagazine.com/css-quarter-circle (I changed the class names because they seemed backwards to me).

And here's the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ingridly/dtauydrz/1/

**UPDATE:**

I incorporated the idea from the other answers of filling another element with the image and grayscale-ing that, and now I think this answer does everything:

https://jsfiddle.net/ingridly/dtauydrz/6/

Comment: that just darkens the image, not grey-scale it as the OP wanted. Kudos for applying the blue border to the darker part, it is the easiest way to align the border.

Comment: Ah, ok. Then I don't think what the OP wants can be done with pure CSS. Css does have `filter: grayscale()` but the effect (if applied to the quarter circle element) wouldn't affect the image below it. You'd need to apply that property to the image itself, which of course makes the whole image grayscale. Unless you break out photoshop to make a separate quarter image (which you already said you want to avoid), I don't think you can do exactly what you desire with CSS. Options then are to darken the image like in my fiddle, or to use Photoshop to color the images.